# Why does my SQLExpress keep disconnecting even though it is shown as running?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I currently face a problem where SQL Server would just consistently drop the connection after a certain period of time.

I've tried restarting the SQL Express service in services.msc, the initial connection/login was successful, but then about 1 minute afterward, any interaction with the Server would just result in the SSMS announcing error 233.

`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)`

It is as though the SQLExpress service has been closed automatically, but then in the Configuration Manager it is still shown as running. The problem does not seem to be with the SSMS as well, as i have tried updating and the error still occur. What is the problem i'm encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Because by default EXPRESS edition creates database with the AUTOCLOSE set to ON.

Reset this functionnality to OFF for the database.